# Why does the term "raising" suggest directionality?

Tags: syntax, terminology

Why does the term "raising" suggest directionality? Consider the sentence

> We want him to buy the groceries.

People who describe such sentences often speak of the subject of "he to buy groceries*" being raised to the object position of the matrix clause to yield "We want him etc."

I don't have nearly enough linguistics knowledge to critique such accounts intelligently. 
I am merely curious about why the above account implies directionality when there aren't any sentences that contain phrases like "he to buy the groceries*".

Comment: The subject of an infinitive takes a _for_ complementizer, the same way the verb takes a _to_ complementizer. Both are often omitted. So the clause is not "he to buy groceries", but rather "for him to buy groceries". The _him_ clearly belongs and originates as the subject of _buy_, but it winds up as the object of _want_ (though this is not so clear with _want_ since it normally doesn't passivize Raised objects). If you use the metaphor of the main clause at the top and the _subordinate_ clauses underneath it, calling it "Raising" seems natural.

Comment: Silly me, I forgot the "for"!  Thanks.

Comment: The fact that **We want [he to buy groceries]* can be 'repaired' by either inserting *for* or raising the embedded subject to the matrix object position suggests that the sentence is bad for reasons of case. In other words, suppose that the subject of an infinitival clause can't be assigned case - it therefore must be moved to a position where it does receive case (complement of *want*), or a prepositional case-assigner *for* must be inserted. That's why these are often referred to as Exceptional Case Marking constructions.

Comment: Note that the pronoun receives oblique case in the good version of the sentence - subjects normally aren't assigned oblique case. This isn't always obvious in a language with impoverished morphology like English, but it's very obvious in many other languages.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the raising is from **we want that he buys groceries* to *we want him to buy groceries*, and the "high" level is the main clause; the content of a fictional subordinate *that* clause is raised to the level of the main clause, in the form of an object plus an infinitive (in this case). After all, *sub*-ordination means "ordering below".

Why do we even posit such a fictional subordinate clause that never really existed? You could argue against this practice. But I think the main reason is semanto-pragmatic; that is, it cannot really be proven syntactically in any way. We somehow presume that there is in language a "standard" model of expressing an agent and a situation that the agent applies a modal opinion to, and that this model is a main clause with agent plus modality, followed by a subordinate clause containing the situation.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work that way. If you want to know what "Raising" means, read Postal's _On Raising_; McCawley 1998 might be helpful for background. [Here's](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) a short summary of Raising and Equi, from a college grammar course; and here are a couple of background guides to [logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) and to the [verb phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf).

Comment: And it's not _*we want that he buys groceries_, but rather _we want for him to buy groceries_. Infinitives take infinitive complementizers.

Comment: @jlawler: Okay, so then could you explain in a few words how it does work? // Very well, use *for* as the fictional/theoretical complementizer in *we want him to*; but why is it to be preferred over *that*, considering that neither construction is actually used with *want*? Or is it? // Or are you saying that *him* in *we want him to* was (historically) felt to be an indirect object, akin to *for him* in *we want for him to*? If so, then perhaps this *for* is not so theoretical?

Comment: _We want for him to VP_ is perfectly grammatical (if uncommon) in my idiolect of English. That's why I said Raising isn't necessarily involved with _want_, which in any case also takes Equi. Pick a better example, like _believe_.

Comment: _He believes there to be nothing left to do_ has already dropped the _for_ and undergone _There_-insertion in the complement clause. Is _there_ the subject of _be_ or the object of _believe_? Yes. And in this one we can't tell. But it can be Passivized - +There is believed to be nothing left to do_. That _there_ has nothing to do with _believe_; it's strictly an appendage of the complement. But it shows up upstairs. That's why it's called _Raising_. That's only one test; there are lots of others in the handout.

Comment: @jlawler:   If you ever give your information as an answer, I will upvote it and check-mark it.  But even if you don't, I appreciate the three links that your provided above.

Comment: @jlawler Why do you say that *for* is dropped in sentences like this, rather than that *for* is inserted in other infinitival clauses (as P Elliott seems to imply in his comments on the OQ)? Isn't it simpler to insert a form only when you can actually see it rather than to insert it and then delete it later in the same derivation?

Comment: If you can predict what the form is, sure. It doesn't really matter which alternant of the Dative Alternation one picks as basic, because the presence of _to_ in _I gave the book to Mary_ is as predictable as its absence in _I gave Mary the book_. The _for_ of the _for..to_ infinitive complementizer is a different matter; it's not a simple alternation -- it's required in some situations, disallowed in others, and optional in still others, all under very different circumstances. In a situation like that, you pick the input that has the most information as the starting point.